# Disable activity in Azure Data factory pipeline without removing it

Tags: azure-data-factory

So I am testing each of the activities of the pipeline and I want to disable some of the activities in it. Essentially there is an activity of sending emails which I want to disable as I wanted to see the output of prior activities.

Offcourse I dont want to remove the email sending activity because it is in the prod environment and not developed by me.

Is there any way to disable it?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You cannot disable one, but what you want to do is possible with the debug option in the editor. Just click on the red circle above any activity and run the debugger, it will run until that activity is complete and stop, allowing you to see the output of those prior to that.

Hope this helped!

Comment: Can you please attach the screenshot where that redcircle

Comment: Also note that the "Debug until" red circle is only available to parent activities. Child activities within for example ForEach and If Condition activities  will not have the option.

Answer (score 1):

This builds on Martin Esteban Zurita's answer, if you need to prevent activities from the beginning or from within the middle of your pipeline running, without deleting them altogether:

You can temporarily change the order of the activities and make the ones you want to disable run at the end of the pipeline instead, (closing any gaps you may have created), then click the last activity you do want to run and click the breakpoint circle icon to prevent the "disabled" activities from running.

Then reinstate the order after testing/debugging.

Answer (score 0):

You could disable the trigger or delay the trigger execution to some date in the future.

Answer (score 0):

I usually copy the activities to another temp pipeline, make your desired debugging and recompose the pipeline in the end if applicable.
Or you can clone the pipeline, delete the desired components and debug it.

Answer (score 0):

A dirty hack.

If you add a Wait task and drag lines from the On Fail condition to the tasks you want to disable this will stop that task running.

( you may need to change other flow lines that rely on that task )

Answer (score 0):

You can now deactivate one or more activities from a pipeline, and we skip them during validation and during pipeline run.
Ref: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/deactivate-activity

Answer (score -8):

Just remove from your dataset and add them again. ;-)