# How to check status of pipeline B from Pipeline A

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I'm solving one problem with Azure Data Factory. I have two data factoy pipelines (for example A, B). Pipeline A is running every 5 minutes. Pipeline B is running every 24 hours (night load). I need to block the run of pipeline A if pipeline B is currently running. Is it possible to check the status of B pipeline, for example directly in the "If Condition" activity, in the A pipeline? Something like:

```
@DataFactory.Pipeline("B").Status
```

Comment: Hi,any updates?

Comment: Hi sorry for delay in my response, but I was longer time offline and then I was too busy. I was limited in services that I can create for my customer. Finally I do the pipeline concurrence run checking inside database (in etl scheme). It was simple and it is working.

Comment: Never mind for the delay and thank you for your solution sharing.I tried to summary it under my answer,would you please accept it an answer which is beneficial for others on the forum. Thx~

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the [System variables supported by Azure Data Factory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/control-flow-system-variables), status is not included in pipeline.

My idea is using [Azure Function activity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/control-flow-azure-function-activity) in your Pipeline B.

step 1: use Azure Function activity and follow this thread [Disable activity in Azure Data factory pipeline without removing it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50243988/disable-activity-in-azure-data-factory-pipeline-without-removing-it) to disable pipeline A.

step 2: do pipeline B

step 3:use Azure Function activity and follow this [sdk](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/monitor-programmatically#net) to start pipeline A.

---

Just for summary here:

Finally,@milos did the pipeline concurrence run checking inside database (in etl scheme) which is working.