# How to skip an execute pipeline activity in a ADF Pipeline and execute other activities in ADF

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I have a pipeline with multiple activities like ExecutePipelineActivity1,ExecutePipelineActivity2, CopyActivity, Delete activity.  in this pipeline I want to disable executepipelineactivity1 and only enable other remaining activities to execute in  pipeline.

Condition is I shouldn't remove the Executepipelineactivity1 from existing pipeline, need only to disable it.

Please help me how can I achieve this.

Comment: Looks like a duplicate question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50243988/disable-activity-in-azure-data-factory-pipeline-without-removing-it

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Disable activity in Azure Data factory pipeline without removing it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50243988/disable-activity-in-azure-data-factory-pipeline-without-removing-it)